# discord bot cant mention user even when i have the user id

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

i just made a discord bot which when i use `$hi @username` it has to mention the user but instead in output i get 

> Hi 
user_id is a number but still cant mention the user

this is my **Code :**

```
client.command()
async def hi(message):

    user_message = str(message.message.content)
    exclude = ["@here", "@everyone"]
    match = re.search("@[^@]+", user_message)
    
    if match:
        mentioned_user = re.findall("\d+", user_message)
        user = client.get_user(int(mentioned_user[0]))
        first_mention = match.group(0)
        if first_mention not in exclude:
            emb = discord.Embed(title='Hi {}'.format(user.mention) , description='' , color=0x00ff00)
            emb.set_image(url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/755342614345154631/1051217269302251591/70f07075-4b06-4c7d-ab49-abe737c0ddd7.gif")
            await message.channel.send(embed=emb)

        else:
            next_mention = re.search("@[^@]+", user_message[match.start() + len(first_mention):])
            if next_mention:
                print(next_mention.group(0))
            else:
                print("NO")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mention users in the title of the embed. You can do it as a field value though.